# Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods security level issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, hosting, cas

I  encountered this error on host.

```
  System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot perform CAS Asserts in Security Transparent methods
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckNReturnSO(PermissionToken permToken, CodeAccessPermission demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Int32 create)
   at System.Security.SecurityRuntime.Assert(PermissionSet permSet, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.PermissionSet.Assert()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.SetTypeFromValue()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.set_Value(Object value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter..ctor(String parameterName, Object value)
```

But in localhost project succesfully run.I'm using asp.net 4.0 and mysql.In some resources say I have to change trust level but I cannot change.Because my hosting firm doesn't allow web config file change for this subject.How can I change trust level without web config change.How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a shared host, so there's no way you can changed trust level if they don't give you permissions to do it.

What versions of the MySQL connector are you using?
Have you tried copying them to the \bin folder of your project? (right-click on MySQL.* references and setting then to "Copy Local = true")

Are you able to try to connect to your database server from localhost to make sure your connection string parameters are ok?

Comment: I'm  using latest version of mysql connector until last week.But one week ago hosting changed something and mysite is down.After that I tried with mysql connector 6.2.5, my site succesfully run on host.Now my site working with mysql connector 6.2.5.So I'm using old version of mysql connector.Does this situation make vulnerable my site for any attack?

Comment: No it does not! Host providers do set less permissions on servers to avoid one customer application to get information from another customer applications/private space. Newer versions of MySql connectors require more privileges... it is how it was built.. can't change that. Change to a new host that can give you more access permissions. More permissions doesn't mean less secure, unless they are not configuring permissions correctly across users/applications on the server.

Comment: I was having this problem with connector 6.5 and onwards. I reverted to 6.2.5 on @dgn's advice and it worked for me also.